tikzplot reading a data file with uneven row data from .csv file creates problem in x expr \thisrowno
I have a data file like this one (it has 4 columns):
Sxy_FEA,x_FEA,x_Analy,Sxy_Analy
0.0000000010137,0,0.99706580118374,0.000267084368331167
0.000000041975,0.005,0.988280423780349,0.000255644263283463
0.000000083973,0.01,0.973695423877779,0.000225725640936805
0.00000012601,0.015,0.953396392054931,0.000193019441142657
0.00000016812,0.02,0.927502451102095,0.000157986067514505
0.00000021032,0.025,0.896165556961056,0.000124919895744515
0.00000025262,0.03,0.859569606987201,9.51939774675699E-05
0.00000029506,0.035,0.817929360766718,7.03575521197382E-05
0.00000033765,0.04,0.771489179821943,5.04140956652429E-05
0.00000038042,0.045,0.720521593600787,3.52528370539707E-05
0.0000004234,0.05,0.665325700165565,2.40578211409463E-05
0.00000046659,0.055,0.606225410966638,1.61509256495565E-05
0.00000051003,0.06,0.543567550001221,1.06563203885991E-05
0.00000055374,0.065,0.477719818512263,6.97945219123504E-06
0.00000059774,0.07,0.40906863717134,4.51176087086137E-06
0.00000064206,0.075,0.338016878408503,2.90990172126299E-06
0.00000068672,0.08,0.264981502196662,1.82866913615476E-06
0.00000073175,0.085,0.190391109164668,1.11719370300617E-06
0.00000077717,0.09,0.1146834253984,5.89192551308499E-07
0.000000823,0.095,0.0383027336900354,1.92423980623496E-07
0.00000086927,0.1,0,0
0.00000091601,0.105,,
0.00000096324,0.11,,
0.000001011,0.115,,
0.0000010593,0.12,,
0.0000011082,0.125,,
0.0000011576,0.13,,
0.0000012077,0.135,,
0.0000012585,0.14,,
0.00000131,0.145,,
0.0000013621,0.15,,
0.0000014151,0.155,,
0.0000014688,0.16,,
0.0000015233,0.165,,
0.0000015787,0.17,,
0.0000016349,0.175,,
0.0000016921,0.18,,
0.0000017503,0.185,,
0.0000018094,0.19,,
0.0000018696,0.195,,
0.0000019308,0.2,,

I am using the following tikzplot commands to plot
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{FIGURES/Fig04anew.csv}\mydata
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
%    VARIABLES
\pgfmathsetmacro{\eaEz}{0.00191742}
      \begin{axis}
      [
        xmin=0,xmax=1.0,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.2,
        xtick distance=0.2,
        ytick distance=0.05,
        minor x tick num=1,
        minor y tick num=1,        
         width=\linewidth*0.6, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
         grid=major, % Display a grid
         grid style={dashed,gray!30}, % Set the style
         xlabel=$x/a$, % Set the labels
         ylabel=$\frac{\tau(x)}{e^a \mathcal{E}_z}$,
         legend style={at={(0.5,0.9)},draw=none}, 
         legend cell align={left},         
         xlabel style={font=\large},
         ylabel style={rotate=-90,font=\Large}
        ]
        \addplot [only marks,
                mark=ball,
                ball color=red,
                mark options={solid},
                mark repeat=3,
                mark size=1.9pt,
                red] 
        table
        [ 
        x expr=\thisrowno{1},
        y expr=\thisrowno{0}/\eaEz,
        col sep=comma
        ] {\mydata};
%
%
        \addplot[solid, color=black,line width = 1.5pt, mark options={solid,fill=magenta}]
        table
        [ 
        x expr=\thisrowno{2},
        y expr=\thisrowno{3}/\eaEz,
        ] {\mydata};
        \legend{{FEA,Analytical}};
      \end{axis}
    \node at (3.3,7.5) {(a)}; 
    \node at (2.3,4.5) [font=\small]{$a/h_1 = 50$}; 
    \node at (2.3,3.8) [font=\small]{$h_1/h_2 = 2$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

It gives me an error. However if I use
        table[x=x_Analy, y expr=\thisrowno{3}/\eaEz] {\mydata};

for the second plot it works just fine. But I want to use "x expr" to do some scaling operations. I think the problem is the number of rows in each column are not equal. Is there a way to solve this problem?
